# Power series of inverse function

Tags: calculus, power-series

Let, $f$ be a bijective function on set of Real numbers. Let, $f(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$ such that $a_{1}=2,a_{2}=4$ let, $f^{-1}(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_nx^n$
Then find value of $b_1$.

My approach:
we know,
$$\frac{1}{1-2x}=1+2x+4x^2+8x^3+\ldots $$
$$\frac{2x}{1-2x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2x)^n $$

Hence,

$$f(x) = \frac{2x}{1-2x}$$

Let, $f(x)=y$

then, $$2x =y(1-2x)$$

$$2x= \frac{y}{1+y}$$

$$x= \frac{y}{2(1+y)}$$
Now,
$$\frac{1}{1+y}= 1-y+y^2-y^3+\ldots$$
$$\frac{y}{2(1+y)}= \frac{y}{2} -\frac{y^2}{2}+\ldots $$

Hence, $b_1=\frac{1}{2}$.

Am I correct?

Comment: This does not make any sense. Who told you that, e.g., $a_3=8$?

Comment: What makes you think that $f(x)=\frac{2x}{1-2x}$ rather than, say, $2x+4x^2$?

Comment: As I understood, you are assuming the "uniqueness of answer". You just proposed a function that satisfies conditions, and conclude by only that example. This is not a rigorous proof or solution.

Comment: Yes Sir, I understand my fault. How can we do Rigorous proof?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot assume anything about $f$ other than the facts that $a_1=2$ and $a_2=4$.

If $f^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nx^n$, then $f^{-1}\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=x$ means that$$b_1(a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots)+b_2(a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots)^2+\cdots=x.\label{a}\tag1$$But the coefficient of $x$ on the LHS of \eqref{a} is $b_1a_1$. So, $b_1a_1=1$. But $a_1=2$. Therefore, $b_1=\frac12$.

Comment: Where did you use $a2=4$? I also don’t understand your logic.

Comment: I did *not* use the fact that $a_2=4$. It's irrelevant. And I cannot explain my logic until you tell me which is there in my answer that you do not understand.

Comment: Because the RHS of $(1)$ is $x$, which is equal to$$1\times x+0\times x^2+0\times x^3+\cdots$$Therefore, all coefficients, other than the coefficient of $x$ are equal to $0$, and the coefficient of $x$ is equal to $1$. Note that you can also argue as follows:$$b_1=\left(f^{-1}\right)'(0)=\frac1{f'\left(f^{-1}(0)\right)}=\frac1{a_1}=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach related to that of [José Carlos Santos](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4641573/147357): if we differentiate the expression $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ implicitly, we find that
$$f'(f^{-1}(x))(f^{-1})'(x)=1,$$
so that $(f^{-1})'(x)=1/f'(f^{-1}(x))$.  This tells us that $b_1=(f^{-1})'(0)=1/f'(f^{-1}(0))$.  Because $f(0)=0$, we know that $f^{-1}(0)=0$, and can conclude that $b_1=(f^{-1})'(0)=1/f'(0)=1/a_1$.

As noted in the comments, you are only given $a_1$ and $a_2$, and cannot conclude anything else about the function $f$.  The fact that you get the correct answer is because any injective function with $a_0=0$ will have $a_1b_1=1$, so your example had to give the correct answer.  But an example does not prove that the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, the general partition polynomials for the inversion of a (formal) o.g.f. / power series are given in OEIS [A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437) and [A111785](https://oeis.org/A111785). These have fascinating connections with the associahedra, trees, lattice paths, . . . ; those for e.g.f.s / Taylor series (A134685), with Grassmannians, trees, balls in bins, . . . ; those using the shifted reciprocal (A134264), with noncrossing partitions, parking functions, Dyck lattice paths, trees, free probability theory, . . . .

As long as $a_1 \neq 0 $, given the first $k$ coefficients of $f(x)$, you can determine the first $k$ coefficients of $f^{(-1)}(x)$. Of course, these sets of partition polynomials are all consistent with the numerous analytic, geometric, and combinatorial ways--each revealing some interesting aspect of inversion--of deriving the compositional inversion (e.g., see [A145271](https://oeis.org/A145271), not exhaustive), but, in addition, they provide links to significant combinatorial constructs.